# how to use sony illumination api

Tags: android, sony

I am trying to create an app that can make the illumination bar light of xperia s blink but not able to download the illumination api. from where should i download com.sonyericsson.illumination libraries??

Comment: possible duplicate of [com.sonyericsson.illumination.jar not present in sony ericsson EDK 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087069/com-sonyericsson-illumination-jar-not-present-in-sony-ericsson-edk-2-0)

Comment: Please don't re-post the exact same question multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

We now have an official API to support Illumination.  See here for more details:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/06/20/new-experimental-illumination-bar-api-available/

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with any sony specific API's

However I would assume that the library that you need would be included with Sony's addon to the Android SDK which can be found in the SDK Manager included with the SDK.

[image]

Comment: i have tried the above method but the required library com.sonyericsson.illumination.jar is not present in the above package